# Handling #define macros in yacc/bison lex

Tags: macros, bison, c-preprocessor, yacc, lex

How would I implement `#define` macros with yacc/bison?

I was thinking all define characters must match a regular variable. Variables are defined as `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` so I figure I can put a check there to see if the variable is a define'd worked or not. Then replace the text with what it should be.

How can i do that? Right now I want to completely ignore the word BAD as if I defined it as `#define BAD` in C. Below is the code for that lex rule but I am doing it wrong. Also lex complains about "BA" being in the stream. I know the below is completely wrong and illogical so how do I ignore BAD and then how do I replace it with something like float

```
    if(strcmp(yytext, "BAD")==0) {
        int i, l = strlen(yytext);
        for(i=0; i<l; i++) { REJECT }
        return;
    }
    return VAR; }
```

I know the major steps are 1) define the define, 2) detect it in source 3) make lex forget the macro characters 4) insert the new correct characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a rule in lex to find the define. Then use unput to insert the replacement text.
Note the text is to be inserted backwards

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]* {
        if(strcmp(yytext, "HARDCODED_DEFINE")==0) {
            const char s[]="int replacement_text";
            int z;
            for(z=strlen(s)-1; z>=0; z--)
                unput(s[z]);
        }
        else
            return VAR_TOK; 
        }
```